# Server response was malformated error with Mega Upload

Tags: devdemon

recently all of a sudden I've just started getting the following error messages with Mega Upload. As far as I'm aware nothing has changed, but obviously something has!

> Server response was malformated, probally a PHP error

I'm running the latest version of Mega Upload and EE.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: we have the same problem but in Safari and Firefox only.
In Chrome it works without any problems. EE 2.10.1 and MU 2.5.5 What could be the problem? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a couple things. First check if you can upload the file in file manager. If you can, then I would look to make sure Flash is installed and then make sure the domain logged in is the exact same url setup for EE, www and all.

If the file manager login doesn't work, then you need to diagnose EE/PHP issues.

If none of this works, make a ticket at DevDemon.com.